# Программно задать архиву свойство "скрытый"

Tags: java

```
public class DOWNLOADING {

    public void DOWNLOADING(String FROM, String WHERE) {

        try {
            Sardine SARDINE = SardineFactory.begin("login", "password");

            InputStream IS = SARDINE.get("https://webdav.yandex.ru" + "/" + FROM);

            File FILE = new File(WHERE);

            OutputStream OS = new FileOutputStream(FILE);

            byte[] BUFFER = new byte[8 * 1024];

            int BR;

            while((BR = IS.read(BUFFER)) != -1) {
                OS.write(BUFFER, 0, BR);
            }

            IS.close();

            OS.close();

            out.print("\n    Skachano\n");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException E) {
            out.print("\n    Oshibka\n");
        }
        catch(IOException E) {
            out.print("\n    Oshibka\n");
        }

    }

}

DOWNLOADING.DOWNLOADING("Путь\Файл.zip", "Путь" + "Файл.zip");
```

В приведённом выше коде я скачиваю архив. Нужно что-бы при скачивании (дальше извлечение) пользователь не видел архив. Пробовал изначально архиву задать свойство "скрытый" но при загрузке на Яндекс.Диск и скачиванию не знаю на каком этапе но свойство не сохраняется. Как сделать так что-бы архив сохранял свойство "скрытый" или как его задать при скачивании?

Например файл будет качаться несколько минут и будет виден в момент скачивания и установки. От этого нужно как-то избавиться. Можно конечно его запихнуть куда подальше но хотелось бы просто скрыть так как после извлечение он удаляется и никому не надо его видеть.

Comment: Ыыыы... хоспаде - это когда-нибудь закончится или нет....

Comment: @Barmaley Что-что?

Comment: просто глядя на ваш код хочется рыдать и плакать :) Не берите близко к сердцу ))

Comment: @Barmaley Подскажите тогда что не так, пожалуйста, я учусь и исправлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам не пробовал, может сработает, попробуйте:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("directory", "hidden.txt");
Boolean hidden = path.getAttribute("dos:hidden", LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
if (hidden != null && !hidden) {
    path.setAttribute("dos:hidden", Boolean.TRUE, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
}
```

*Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-hide-file-java-program-example.html#ixzz4aedtSbiH*

Для Вашего случая может и не подойти, но если в `path` получится дать ссылку на файл `path.setAttribute("dos:hidden",` - может и сработает...

Может, и от сюда что-то найдется: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294989/make-a-file-folder-hidden-on-windows-with-java

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях принято создавать временный файл:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("mytempfile", ".tmp");
```

и писать все туда. А потом после окончания скачивания, просто переименовать его в нужное название и все.

P.S. почитайте про стандарты [Java naming convention](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) - а то правда сердце кровью обливается.

Comment: То есть сохранять файл с расширением .tmp а потом переименовывать в нужный?

Comment: Например, да... Но нужно создавать именно временный файл, чтобы избежать коллизии имен (вдруг такой уже имеется)

Comment: Я вот сейчас создал файл с расширением .tmp и он не скрытый.

Comment: Зачем вы хотите его скрывать?!

Comment: Так я же изначально в вопросе написал зачем. Что-бы не было видно процесса установки, как качаются файлы и лежат в файловой системе пока программа не извлечёт архив и не удалит его.

Comment: Дык, если у него будет расширение .tmp он никому и мешать то не будет - никто и знать не будет, что это архив какой-то. К тому же его можно писать в системный каталог *temp* - тогда до него вообще никому дела не будет

Comment: Опять же я в вопросе написал что можно файл запихнуть куда-нибудь но хотелось бы просто скрыть его.

Comment: Ладно, я все - я пас

Comment: Это проще всего :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне вот это помогло [по ссылке](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-hide-file-java-program-example.html#ixzz4aedtSbiH). Существующему файлу меняем аттрибут:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRunTime().exec("attrib +h" + namefile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    //Ignore Error
}
```

Comment: Не подскажете, по какой ссылке выше?

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-hide-file-java-program-example.html#ixzz4aedtSbiH      - Пример кода смотрите в комментариях от "Anonymous said..."